# SQLite data disappears after being updated

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I've created an empty table in a sqlite database, DB, via a database adapter.

Since I have a lot of data (10,000+ rows) to be inserted and I don't want to do it in the activities so I pull the sqlite database out of data/data/package-name/databases and inserted the rows via sqlite browser software. I then reinserted/push the updated DB it back into the eclipse DDMS and all was fine at first.

The DB has an inflated size of 800kb from the original 22kb.

But after running the emulator again, I noticed that the DB shrunk back to 22kb and upon pulling it out and inspecting it, the rows I inserted is no longer there.

Strange enough, the DB journal file in the same folder is now inflated to 800kb, but I can not open that file (sqlite browser says the file is either corrupt or encrypted but not a valid Sqlite file). Can someone explain what happened?

Answer (score 0):

Did you commit changes after updating database? Also check if database is not dropped when Eclipse uninstall old version of the application before new one is deployed on target.

Comment: I'm new to sqlite and android in general. How do I 'commit changes' to the database? I agree with you, after thinking it through, I believe the empty table has been recreated to take place of the one with the data but am not sure how to make sure it doesn't?

Comment: It depends of what framework you have. Try to type some keywords into stackoverflow fore more help.